# Re. partitions()

Tags: julia, combinatorics

Why is

```
julia> collect(partitions(1,2))
0-element Array{Any,1}
```

returned instead of

```
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 [0,1]
 [1,0]
```

and do I really have to

```
x = collect(partitions(n,m));
y = Array(Int64,length(x),length(x[1]));
for i in 1:length(x)
    for j in 1:length(x[1])
        y[i,j] = x[i][j];
    end
end
```

to convert the result to a two-dimensional array?

Comment: i think it calculates vectors of non zero elements.

Answer (score 3):

From the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)):

> In number theory and combinatorics, a partition of a positive integer n, also called an integer partition, is a way of writing n as a sum of positive integers.

For array conversion, try:

```
julia> x = collect(partitions(5,3))
2-element Array{Any,1}:
 [3,1,1]
 [2,2,1]
```

or

```
julia> x = partitions(5,3)
Base.FixedPartitions(5,3)
```

then

```
julia> hcat(x...)
3x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 3  2
 1  2
 1  1
```

Comment: I think this answers the 2nd question, but not the first. I'd recommend you include @Reza's comment in your answer to have a more complete solution.

Comment: @niczky12 Yes, I didn't really understand that part of the question — presumably they're not including 0s, because they'd be in every possible partition...

Comment: Is this a difference of opinion about the meaning of the word "partitions"? I seem to remember there was a previous discussion about this, not sure if here or on julia-users.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders No idea, the only partitions I know anything about are those separating workers in cubicles... :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the hcat(x...) tidbit is gold. I guess if zero is not counted as a positive integer then the implementation makes sense. The order of the summands are important in many applications (mine for instance), but I guess only listing unique unordered solutions is also valid in many settings.

Comment: `0` is never counted as a [positive integer](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveInteger.html). If you care about the order of summands, you want a "composition", not a "partition". This is the mathematical terminology. (I don't know if a "compositions" function exists; maybe check Combinatorics.jl?)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach to your problem that I think is a little simpler, using the Combinatorics.jl library:

```
multisets(n, k) = map(A -> [sum(A .== i) for i in 1:n],
                      with_replacement_combinations(1:n, k))
```

This allocates a bunch of memory, but I think your current approach does too. Maybe it would be useful to make a first-class version and add it to Combinatorics.jl.

Examples:

```
julia> multisets(2, 1)
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1,0]
 [0,1]

julia> multisets(3, 5)
21-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [5,0,0]
 [4,1,0]
 [4,0,1]
 [3,2,0]
 [3,1,1]
 [3,0,2]
 [2,3,0]
 [2,2,1]
 [2,1,2]
 [2,0,3]
 ⋮      
 [1,2,2]
 [1,1,3]
 [1,0,4]
 [0,5,0]
 [0,4,1]
 [0,3,2]
 [0,2,3]
 [0,1,4]
 [0,0,5]
```

The argument order is backwards from yours to match mathematical convention. If you prefer the other way, that can easily be changed.

Comment: That is really nice and compact. I was fiddling around the (at)time macro to see if there would be any difference in your code, and the code I ported from MATLAB to Julia... (at)time x = nsumk(k,n) and (at)time y = hcat(multisets(n,k)...)', gives 0.007708 seconds (36.51 k allocations: 2.708 MB) and 1.065818 seconds (342.59 k allocations: 1.603 GB, 11.95% gc time), respectively, for k = 10000 and n = 2. That seems like a significant difference...

Comment: I wouldn't mind contributing the the Combinatorics.jl module, but I just started using Julia last week, so I need to figure out how to do it :)

Comment: @Arnfinn: You're definitely right! This code allocates a lot of memory, as I had predicted, but apparently much **much** more memory than I had predicted. I don't know how much better one could make it while maintaining the same approach; this approach is simply not that good.

Answer (score 2):

one robust solution can be achieved using *lexicographic premutations generation* algorithm, originally **By Donald Knuth** plus classic `partitions(n)`.
that is lexicographic premutations generator:

```
function lpremutations{T}(a::T)
  b=Vector{T}()
  sort!(a)
  n=length(a)
  while(true)
    push!(b,copy(a))    
    j=n-1
    while(a[j]>=a[j+1])
      j-=1
      j==0 && return(b)
    end
    l=n
    while(a[j]>=a[l])
      l-=1
    end
    tmp=a[l]
    a[l]=a[j]
    a[j]=tmp
    k=j+1
    l=n
    while(k<l)
      tmp=a[k]
      a[k]=a[l]
      a[l]=tmp
      k+=1
      l-=1
    end
  end
end
```

The above algorithm will generates all possible unique
combinations of an array elements with repetition:

```
julia> lpremutations([2,2,0])
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [0,2,2]
 [2,0,2]
 [2,2,0]
```

Then we will generate all integer arrays that sum to n using `partitions(n)` (forget the length of desired arrays **m**), and resize them to the lenght **m** using `resize_!`

```
function resize_!(x,m)
  [x;zeros(Int,m-length(x))]
end
```

And main function looks like:

```
function lpartitions(n,m)
  result=[]
  for i in partitions(n)
    append!(result,lpremutations(resize_!(i, m)))
  end
  result
end
```

**Check it**

```
julia> lpartitions(3,4)
20-element Array{Any,1}:
 [0,0,0,3]
 [0,0,3,0]
 [0,3,0,0]
 [3,0,0,0]
 [0,0,1,2]
 [0,0,2,1]
 [0,1,0,2]
 [0,1,2,0]
 [0,2,0,1]
 [0,2,1,0]
 [1,0,0,2]
 [1,0,2,0]
 [1,2,0,0]
 [2,0,0,1]
 [2,0,1,0]
 [2,1,0,0]
 [0,1,1,1]
 [1,0,1,1]
 [1,1,0,1]
 [1,1,1,0]
```

Comment: Thanks for this -- of course Knuth has something to say about it :) This approach, I think, is very easy to understand.

Comment: I did some timing of this code as well: with n = 2; k = 75; nsumk(k,n) gives 0.005902 seconds (6.72 k allocations: 310.617 KB), multisets(n,k) gives 0.006589 seconds (6.32 k allocations: 1.005 MB), and lpartitions(k,n) gives 1.479605 seconds (16.25 M allocations: 1.743 GB, 8.52% gc time) ...

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB script from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28340-nsumk actually behaves the way I need, and is what I though that partitions() would do from the description given. The Julia version is

```
# k - sum, n - number of non-negative integers
function nsumk(k,n)
  m = binomial(k+n-1,n-1);
  d1 = zeros(Int16,m,1);
  d2 = collect(combinations(collect((1:(k+n-1))),n-1));
  d2 = convert(Array{Int16,2},hcat(d2...)');
  d3 = ones(Int16,m,1)*(k+n);
  dividers = [d1 d2 d3];
  return diff(dividers,2)-1;
end

julia> nsumk(3,2)
4x2 Array{Int16,2}:
 0  3
 1  2
 2  1
 3  0
```

using daycaster's lovely hcat(x...) tidbit :)
I still wish there would be a more compact way of doing this.

The the first mention of this approach seem to be https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/52610, and as far as I can understand it is based on the "stars and bars" method https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)

Comment: Effectively, this is generating multisets of size S chosen from n symbols. This might be a useful function to have in some situations. Maybe consider adding it to Combinatorics.jl?