# partition of n with part k without permutations in Julia

Tags: julia

My code was taking from  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37296557/re-partitions):

```
function partition(n,k)
  p=with_replacement_combinations(1:n,k)
  return map(A -> [sum(A .== i) for i in 1:n],p)
end
```

`julia>partition(3,4)`

I want to get

```
[4, 0, 0]
[3, 1, 0]
[2, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 1]
```

instead of

```
 [4, 0, 0]
 [3, 1, 0]
 [3, 0, 1]
 [2, 2, 0]
 [2, 1, 1]
 [2, 0, 2]
 [1, 3, 0]
 [1, 2, 1]
 [1, 1, 2]
 [1, 0, 3]
 [0, 4, 0]
 [0, 3, 1]
 [0, 2, 2]
 [0, 1, 3]
 [0, 0, 4]
```

so that  `[0, 0, 4] , [4, 0, 0]` and `[0, 4, 0]` are the same.

So   `[3, 1, 0] , [3, 0, 1], [1, 0, 3], [0, 1, 3], [0, 3, 1],` and `[1, 3, 0]` are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: A second option taking less code is:

```
using Combinatorics
genlist2(n,k) = vcat([vcat.(collect(partitions(n,i)),Ref(fill(0,3-i))) for i=1:k]...)
```

Again `genlist2(4,3)` gives the desired list.

Furthermore, this can be adapted to be an iterator, which doesn't materialize all the partitions:

```
import Base.Iterators as Itr
genlist3(n,k) = Itr.map(v->vcat(v,fill(0,k-length(v))),Itr.flatten(Itr.map(i->partitions(n,i),1:k)))
```

Giving:

```
julia> genlist3(4,3) |> collect
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [4, 0, 0]
 [3, 1, 0]
 [2, 2, 0]
 [2, 1, 1]
```

ORIG SOLUTION:

The following functions seems to do the work. It operates recursively, with depth limited by number of parts which should be small enough not to trigger a stack overflow.

```
function genlist(n,k,m = n)
    n < 0 && error("n must be non-negative")
    k < 0 && error("k must be non-negative")
    m < 0 && error("m must be non-negative")
    k == 0 && n > 0 && return Vector{Int}[]
    n == 0 && return [fill(0,k)]
    n == 1 && m > 0 && return [vcat(1, fill(0,k-1))]
    m > n && (m = n)
    L = [[vcat(i,ll) for ll in genlist(n-i,k-1,i)] for i in m:-1:1]
    return vcat(L...)
end
```

The test case in the OP:

```
julia> genlist(4,3)
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [4, 0, 0]
 [3, 1, 0]
 [2, 2, 0]
 [2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Perfect ; the second solution works for general case

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something here as I'm sure Dan would have given the obvious answer if it's also the best, but it seems to me that a small variation of your original approach gives the desired answer?

```
julia> [x for x ∈ with_replacement_combinations(0:4, 3) if sum(x) ==4]
4-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [0, 0, 4]
 [0, 1, 3]
 [0, 2, 2]
 [1, 1, 2]
```